# Flutter Live Broadcast using WebRTC

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I need to do a Live Broadcast apps using flutter on both iOS and Android.

While broadcasting, the video can be recorded by both the broadcaster and viewer (Up to 500).

I have did some studies and seems like WebRTC is the way to go. But I need to know some additional info:

1. How can broadcast be done? Send to a server and the server will send to individual viewer separately?
2. Can I put something overlay on the video while it is playing? Example: Text, Icons, Buttons .... etc

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc-demo

Comment: Thanks @IronMan, I have been testing using that website as well. But unfortunately it doesn't have documentation, and I really do not know if there is a better way to do broadcasting, and well as overlaying images / controls on the video.

Comment: You could take a look at janus streaming plugin:
https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/streaming.html.
You could use this to forward your webrtc stream to youtube live for example, and embbed it in your app